# How to find largest absolute value fro repeatitive rows in multiple columns in Python and also show its row and column index

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, max

[image: Useful Image]

I am new to python. I want to find the largest values from all the columns for repetitive row elements (i.e. 5 to 4100), and also show its row and column index label in output.The largest value should be absolute. (Irrespective of + or - sign)
The group of row indexes will keep on repeating for 'n'number of times. For every 'nth' group of row index, I want largest values and their index positions for each group.
Eg.: If the group Row index repeates 'n' times, output should show 'n' values.

In my dataset, Rows index 5,10,12,101,4100 repeates twice in same sequence. So my output must show 2 largest values,(1 from each group).
If my row index(5,10,12,101,4100) repeats 'n' times in same sequence, Output must display 'n' values.(1 value for each group of rows)

[image: Please See This Image]

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'E_at_0': [43, -53, 45, -17, 45, 19, 11, 32, 36, 32], 
                   'E_at_10': [-47, 47, 46, -18, 53, 16, 12, 34, -71, -34], 
                   'E_at_20': [56, 43, 41, 29, 36, 14, 13, -37, 43, 38], 
                   'E_at_30': [-46, 16, -40, 31, 42, 15, 63, -39, 52, 39]}, index=[5, 10, 12, 101, 4100, 5, 10, 12, 101, 4100])

df.index.name='Ele_Num'
```

```
df = pd.read_csv ('trial.csv')

df = df.set_index('Ele_Num')

s = df.abs().stack()

mask = s == s.max()

df1 = df.stack()[mask].reset_index()

df1.columns = ['Element No','Column','Values']

print (df1)

df1.to_csv('trial_output.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=True)
```

Expected Results:

For 1st set of rows (i.e. for index 5,10,12,101,4100)

```
Ele_Num   E_at_20
  5          56
```

For 2nd group of row index values(i.e.again for index 5,10,12,101,4100)

```
Ele_Num   E_at_10
  101       -71
```

Actual Results:

```
Ele_Num   E_at_30
  101       -71
```

Comment: Please reformat it properly. You said `Please see the image` where as there is no url .

Comment: Done. Please Check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create groups and then call function per groups - last select in output DataFrame by indices with `loc`:

```
def f(x):
    x1 = x.abs().stack()
    x2 = x.stack()
    x = x2.iloc[np.argsort(-x1)].head(2)
    return x

groups = (df.index == 5).cumsum()
df1 = df.groupby(groups).apply(f).reset_index(level=[1,2])
df1.columns = ['Element No','Column','Values']
print (df1)
   Element No   Column  Values
1           5  E_at_20      56
1          10   E_at_0     -53
2         101  E_at_10     -71
2          10  E_at_30      63

print (df1.loc[1])
   Element No   Column  Values
1           5  E_at_20      56
1          10   E_at_0     -53

print (df1.loc[2])
   Element No   Column  Values
2         101  E_at_10     -71
2          10  E_at_30      63
```

Comment: Your Code provides the exact desired output. For 'n' number of groups, it exactly provides 'n' largest values for each group of row indexes. Thanks for all the support.